# Opportunity Validation Rule not working

Tags: validation-rule

I've got a validation rule that won't work.

```
IF(AND( ISPICKVAL( Type , "Project scoping"), Account.TotalAvailableCredits__c =0 ),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Essentially, it's supposed to display an error message if the opportunity type is equal to "Project scoping" and the available credits (TotalAvailableCredits__c =0) on the associated account is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the TotalAvailableCredits on the related Account equals 0 and not null? Also, have you confirmed that the Validation Rule is active?

I tested it on a sandbox and it worked as expected.

Edit: After reading you comment I changed it in order to apply for both null/0 values.

```
IF(AND( ISPICKVAL( Type , "Projectscoping"),                             
     OR( ISBLANK(Account.TotalAvailableCredits__c),                          
      Account.TotalAvailableCredits__c =0))    
                                     ,TRUE,
FALSE)
```

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes the rule is active and the format of the TotalAvailableCredits is a number format, hence not null - or am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong indeed @JoachimMeulengracht :) 
If the value of the number field is null it will not be treated as zero. I tested for both values and the VR does not fire when the TotalAvailableCredits field is null.

Comment: `IF(expression, true, false)` is the same as `expression`